# Подсветка синтаксиса PHP,HTML,JS,SQL на сайте

Tags: синтаксис, php, javascript

Заканчиваю свой блог, осталось только в админке  сделать нормально добавления статьи. Но в ручную очень-очень долго выделять код, т.е. делать подсветку синтаксиса. Есть какие-нибудь скрипты для этого PHP или javascript? Подскажите лучший, которым сами пользуетесь, пожалуйста.
**UPD:**   Подскажите пожалуйста, в каком из этих скриптов можно выделить строку в коде? Т.е. выложил код в статью и хотелось бы обратить внимание на несколько строк в этом коде, подсветить их чтоли.

Comment: [http://prismjs.com/](http://prismjs.com) список сайтов использующих этот плагин говорит за себя

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/)
- [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/index.php)
- [Quick Highlighter](http://quickhighlighter.com/)
- [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)
- [Highlight.JS](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/)
- [SHJS](http://shjs.sourceforge.net/)
- [Chili](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-chili-js/)
- [beautyOfCode](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/10/30/beautyofcode-jquery-plugin-for-syntax-highlighting/)
- [JUSH](http://jush.sourceforge.net/)

Посмотрите примеры, выберите, что вам по душе.

Comment: @mctrane не забывайте кешировать это дело :-)

Comment: Как кешировать? И зачем?

Comment: @mctrane как кешировать Вы найдете в интернете, либо спросите. Зачем кешировать - экономить ресурсы сервера. Обработка текста не такое уж и простое занятие.

Comment: > Зачем кешировать - экономить ресурсы сервера. 

Все упомянутые подсвечивалки на клиентской стороне работают же. Кроме `Quick Highlighter`.

Comment: понятно, а кеширование делать браузером, или прям сохранять в файл на сервере?

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, в каком из этих скриптов можно выделить строку в коде? Т.е. выложил код в статью и хотелось бы обратить внимание на несколько строк в этом коде, подсветить их чтоли.